# How to pass vector elements by reference in c++?

Tags: c++

I have a vector and I need to pass its elements to functions of the type:

```
bool doIt(MyClass &a);
```

so I need to do later:

```
vector<MyClass> v;
doIt(v[2]);
```

I am not sure if I am doing it right...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am not sure if I am doing it right...

**Yes**, you are doing it right, **except** that in your sample code the vector `v` does not contain any element, so the index 2 is out-of-bounds, and this expression:

```
v[2]
```

Results in *undefined behavior*. This would be enough to fix it though (if `MyClass` is default-constructible):

```
vector<MyClass> v(3);
//                ^
//                Creates a vector of 3 default-constructed 
//                elements of type MyClass
doIt(v[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's check the documentation!

[http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator[]/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5b%5d/)

```
reference operator[] (size_type n);
const_reference operator[] (size_type n) const;
```

> Returns a reference to the element at position n in the vector container.

Looks like you're good.

Answer (score 1):

```
doIt(v[2]);
```

That is absolutely correct if `2` is a valid index (which means it is less than `v.size()`). It passes the argument by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct (assuming `v[2]` exists of course), because `std::vector`'s `operator []` returns a reference.

Answer (score 0):

Thats correct the operator[] returns by reference and the doIt function takes by reference so just remember you could modify the elements in your vector.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code (if v.size() is >= 3), but when you resize your vector your reference may become invalid.